# Counting the total number of relations and mapping it to a Result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, counting

Given a `Post` type document as:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Post {
    String publisher;
    Set<String> interests;
}
```

From a collection of posts I am seeking to find out the `Set<Result>` such that the `Result` object would look like:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
class Result {
    String interestId;
    String publisherId;
    Long count;
}
```

---

To  compare the operation with a [java](/questions/tagged/java) implementation, I am looking for something down the lines of the following method:

```
Set<Result> buildQuery(List<Post> postList) {
    return postList.stream()
            .flatMap(post -> post.getInterests().stream()
                    .map(interest -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(interest, post.getPublisher())))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new Result(e.getKey().getKey(), e.getKey().getValue(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

---

While translating this to the mongodb query, this what I have until now:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
 {"$unwind" :"$interestIds"},
 {"$group" : {"_id": {interestId: "$interestIds", publisherId:"$publisherId"}, "count": {"$sum" : 1}}},
]);
```

This results in documents such as:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "interestId" : "INTEREST1",
        "publisherId" : "PUBLISHER2"
    },
    "count" : 3.0
}
```

Now, I am struggling to solve for the end `map` operation to formulate this into an expected result which would be:

```
{
    "_id" : ...
    "interestId" : "INTEREST1",
    "publisherId" : "PUBLISHER2"
    "count" : 3.0
}
```

How can I fix my query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is an equivalent of Java's map:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {"$unwind" :"$interestIds"},
    {"$group" : {"_id": {interestId: "$interestIds", publisherId:"$publisherId"}, "count": {"$sum" : 1}}},
    {"$project":{ _id: 0, interestId: "$_id.interestId", publisherId: "$_id.publisherId", count: 1 }}
]);
```